# Cut inner lists to equal length in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Let's say we have a list of lists, and we want to cut all inner lists down to the length of the shortest inner list -- for instance, from `[[1,2,3,4],[2,3],[3,9]]` we should get `[[1,2],[2,3],[3,9]]`.

This is my code up to now (it doesn't work):

```
cut :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
cut = map (\xs -> drop ((min(length xs)) - length xs) xs)
```

I tried to solve it like this:
There has to be a function that returns the length of the shortest list and, with that, we need a further function that cuts all the lists from the beginning to this new length.
But, in fact, I don't have a clue.

Comment: Why do you drop the 4 ? I don't understand the desired output.

Comment: Ah ok you truncate to the length of the shortest inner list ?

Comment: Not only the 4, the shortest list has two elements so the first list has 4 elements so we need to cut out 2. the 3 and 4.

Comment: to your question: yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it what you want ?

```
truncateList :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
truncateList list = map (\x -> take l x) list
  where
  l = minimum (map length list)
```

or, shorter,

```
truncateList :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
truncateList list = map (take l) list
  where
  l = minimum (map length list)
```

Comment: This is a good example of where it’s okay to use a partial function like `minimum`—if the input is empty, then `minimum` will never be called, and the output will be empty. Unfortunately, because of `length`, this doesn’t work on infinite lists like the `ZipList` solution does.

Comment: You can inline the `l` in your shorter code snippet to make it even shorter.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to zip together an arbitrary number of lists, stopping as soon as the shortest list "runs out", this looks like a job for ZipList.

Let's start by wrapping each of the input lists in the ZipList wrapper type:

```
truncateList :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
truncateList xs = let lists = map ZipList xs
                      ...
                  in ...
```

Now, we have `lists :: [ZipList a]`, and we wish to fold over that list somehow, combining all of the `ZipList a` values into a single ZipList where all the excess elements have been trimmed out. For that, a good tool is

```
sequenceA :: [ZipList a] -> ZipList [a]
```

and so we can write

```
truncateList :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
truncateList xs = let lists = map ZipList xs
                      inverted = sequenceA lists
                  in ...
```

At this point `inverted` is close to the result that you wanted, but not quite: instead of `[[1,2],[2,3],[3,9]]` we have `ZipList [[1,2,3],[2,3,9]]`: the list is transposed, and it's wrapped in a newtype we no longer want. So, we unwrap it, and use `Data.List.transpose` to flip it back the way we want:

```
truncateList :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
truncateList xs = let lists = map ZipList xs
                      inverted = sequenceA lists
                  in transpose (getZipList inverted)
```

And finally we can note that all of this is just composing several built-in functions together:

```
import Data.List (transpose)
import Control.Applicative (ZipList(..))

truncateList :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
truncateList = transpose . getZipList . sequenceA . map ZipList
```

My motivation for finding a ZipList solution was to try to avoid the extra work involved in calling `length` and `take` on each of the input lists, traversing each several times. I'm not so sure my solution succeeded in this goal: as far as I can tell `sequenceA` traverses each list once, and `transpose` tranverses them again, so it's probably about as expensive. It's not really easier to read, either: the solution using `length` and `take` is quite clear.

I do think it's a bit pretty though, and a useful exercise to recognize that this problem looks relatively simple when transposed into a different domain, i.e. the universe of `ZipList`s.

Comment: This has the advantage of both avoiding partial functions and working correctly on infinite lists. As long as one of the input lists is finite (e.g. `[[1, 2], [3..], [4..]]`), it will produce a result (`[[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5]]`). If *all* of the input lists are infinite, it will only be productive up to the original number of inputs: `take 3 $ map (take 2) $ truncateList [[1..], [2..], [3..]]` terminates.

Comment: This version appears to choke on the input `[]`.

Comment: Fascinating. `sequenceA ([] :: [ZipList a])` evaluates to `ZipList (repeat [])`. Makes some sense, since `repeat` is the only reasonable implementation of `pure` for a ZipList, and not incorrect: transposing that should produce `[]`. But it's sorta hard to implement transpose in that way.

Answer (score 4):

I think this version is more efficient than the others, because it only traverses the input list once, generating thunks with pointers to the future.

```
cut xss = let (ret, len) = foldr (\xs (ret', len') ->
                                   (take len xs : ret', min len' (length xs))
                                 ) ([], maxBound) xss
           in ret
```

Note how `len` appears in its own definition. While the `foldr` is being evaluated, it keeps track of both the shortest length and the cut list, and it also has a pointer to where `len` will eventually be. When it adds a new list on top of the cut one, it doesn’t actually create the list, but simply writes a bit of code that represents the expression `take len xs` (this is a consequence of laziness), which refers to `len` via the aforementioned pointer. When the loop ends, the final value of `len` is written at the other end of the pointer, and, in a bit of "action-at-distance", ends up "updating" all the `take` thunks with the correct length.

This version is similar, but, instead of using a finite type to hold the length of the list, I define the type of natural numbers plus infinity. This performs better than the `ZipList` solution, but worse than the finite-only solutions, and it is the only one, so far, that correctly handles infinite lists.

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
-- data [()] = [] | (:) () [()]
-- [()] is isomorphic to Nat, so a lot of these functions in the where
-- clause are just list ones in disguise. Nat appears to perform
-- better, though.
cut :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
cut xss = let (ret, len) = foldr (\xs (ret', len') ->
                                   (take' len xs : ret', min' len' (length' xs))
                                 ) ([], inf) xss
           in ret
  where inf = S inf -- repeat ()
        take' Z _ = [] -- flip (zipWith const)
        take' (S n) (x : xs) = x : take' n xs
        min' Z _ = Z -- zipWith const
        min' _ Z = Z
        min' (S n) (S m) = S $ min' n m
        length' [] = Z -- void
        length' (x:xs) = S $ length' xs
```

Comment: I took a leaf out of your answer [to write a *recursion-schemes* variation on the theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49483487/2751851).

Answer (score 1):

This `cut` is very much like [HTNW's second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49458796/2751851) (and seems to perform exactly as well as that one); however, instead of explicitly using a laziness trick I rely on [`hylo` from *recursion-schemes*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.2/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:hylo) to fuse the traversals.

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH

-- At first, I used [()] instead; as HTNW describes, Nat does seem to 
-- improve performance
data Nat = Z | S Nat

-- A list, annotated at the end with the length to be used for cutting.
data CutList a = Cutter Nat | CutCons a (CutList a)
makeBaseFunctor ''CutList

cut :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
cut = snd . hylo algCut coalgSetup . (inf,) 
    where
    coalgSetup = \case
        (cutter, []) -> CutterF cutter
        (cutter, xs : xss) -> CutConsF xs (min' cutter (length' xs), xss)
    algCut = \case
        CutterF cutter -> (cutter, [])
        CutConsF xs (cutter, xss) -> (cutter, take' cutter xs : xss)
    inf = S inf
    take' (S n) (x : xs) = x : take' n xs
    take' _ _ = []
    min' (S n) (S m) = S (min' n m)
    min' _ _ = Z
    length' [] = Z
    length' (x : xs) = S (length' xs)
```

(This might have been more comfortable to express as some sort of zygo-hylomorphism, but then I would have to define such a thing in the style of *recursion-schemes* to get good performance, and that would have been too distracting.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could get some ideas from this. The functions and assignments all seem to have correspondences in your function.

```
let nl = [[1..4],[2,3],[3,9]]
let min = minimum $ map length nl
map (take min) nl 
[[1,2],[2,3],[3,9]]
```

if there is objection to the use of length then try.

```
(\(a:b:c:xs) -> zip3 a b c ) [[1..5],[2..5],[3..5]]
[(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5)]
```

This only works with three lists but the functions above will work with any number.